# the mechanism by which the alleged complaint was made

Tags: word-usage

> Liberty would not identify the complainant of 3 years ago, the nature of that complaint, or **the mechanism by which the alleged complaint was made.** But she says that complainant is also one of the four women whose complaints launched the probe that began in November 2017.

Source: Science
[Prominent geneticist out at UC Irvine after harassment finding](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2018/06/prominent-geneticist-out-uc-irvine-after-harassment-finding)

I don't quite understand the meaning of the word "mechanism" here. It seems to me that it means "criteria" or "standa rd" here. That is, "by what standard did you make the complaint"? Or it can mean "system" - a system of anti-harassment. I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does mean *system*. That might consist of the sub-organization the complaint is delivered to, and whether it is a formal or informal channel, with the complaint in verbal or written form, with or without witness statements. *Mechanism* is non-specific.

Comment: I would say that 'mechanism' means 'route' or 'method'. The complaint might have been made in writing, verbally, or by email, to the university authorities, to the police, or a student welfare office, etc.